# How is a shared memory bus used for reads and writes of data shared between threads safely and correctly?

Tags: memory, cpu

I would like to understand at a high level how the shared memory bus handles multiple concurrent read and writes of shared data from multiple threads running in multiple processors?

P.S: I do not need the gory details because it is obviously going to be implementation specific. I just need a high level overview of what goes on behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you stuck some where with your own research? What is your understanding so far?

Comment: @DaveRook As far as I understood memory bus is required to communicate between processor and the RAM(main memory). It is called *shared* as it will be used by multiple cores at the same time. Question is more specifically regarding how this shared bus is used without corrupting shared data that flows between them. I am looking for a high level answer here.

Comment: Now that is a better question :) ! I suggest you edit your original post with this as you'll hopefully get more answers.

Comment: @DaveRook updated the question as per your suggestion. Hopefully now would receive a lot of quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

A "bus" is a set of wires between components rather than a component itself. So the wiring between a CPU and its memory is called a memory bus; the wiring to the expansion cards is the PCI bus, etc.

It is possible to have multiple components driving a bus, although only one can drive it at once, and its signals are delivered to all the other components on the bus. The component which controls access to the bus is called the bus *master*. It may be possible to change which component is the bus master by *arbitration*.

In a multi-core system, cache consistency is important. So when one core writes to the shared memory bus, other cores will *snoop* the bus (examine the write even though it's going from another core to the memory). If the write is to a location cached by that core, then the core will evict or replace its cache entry. That way it does not have stale information.

Comment: "It is possible to have multiple components driving a bus, although only one can drive it at once, and its signals are delivered to all the other components on the bus." -- What are the multiple components driving the *memory bus*?

Comment: @Geek In PC chipsets I don't think we've ever had more than one. It used to be the "northbridge" (memory controller/hub), now it's the memory controller built into the CPU. This has not always been the case. In classic minicomputers like the original PDP-11 the memory just sat on the Unibus along with the I/O devices and both CPU and DMA devices could "drive" it. A simple bus arbitration protocol ensured that only one device could do so at one time, and was also used to implement interrupts of vairous priorities (BR, "bus request" levels).

Answer (score 1):

A memory module (a DIMM) can only do one thing at a time: A read or a write. This is dictated by the protocol at the DIMM's edge connector; once you send a read or write command to a DIMM it can't even "hear" another one until the previous command is complete.

All of the DIMMs on a common memory bus will collectively have this one-at-a-time restriction. But on many PC platforms there are two or three memory *channels*, and all the RAM on one channel can collectively do just one thing at a time.

On NUMA machines (those with multiple CPU sockets and "private" memory for each socket) all this is multiplied by nCPUs. i.e. each CPU can be accessing its local memory regardless of what the other CPU is doing with *its* memory. However all CPUs can still access all RAM, it just takes a little longer if they have to go through another CPU.

Fundamentally it is up to applications' code to implement whatever serialization requirements they have for access to shared data. This is done with assistance from the operating system, which will provide various synchronization objects and  functions for the apps to use. These objects have names like semaphores (name borrowed from the railroad signal), mutexes (short for "mutual exclusion"), etc. Depending on the OS they can implement one-at-a-time, n-at-a-time, exclusive write vs. shared read, etc., semantics. These functions usually involve "waiting" or "blocking": A thread tries to e.g. acquire a mutex that, by design, "protects" a shared resource. If the mutex is already owned by some other thread then the second (and _n_th) requesting thread is blocked, i.e. waits and does not return from the acquire call, until the previous owner releases it.

It is up to the applications to use these techniques where necessary; the operating system has no way of requiring that e.g. you have to own a particular mutex before accessing the data you intended the mutex to protect. This is an area of program design that can be very difficult to both get right and have high performance.

Higher-level subsystems like databases have this coding built in for the data they manage and present an interface to the programmer that "speaks" in terms of database elements rather than synchronization objects: The programmer would invoke functions to lock a table row, or an individual cell, or a set of rows, or maybe an entire table, while it performs updates. Underneath the database engine will be using the OS's facilities as previously described.

Internally the operating system generally implements these synchronization functions with the aid of some sort of atomic test-and-modify operation that's implemented in the memory subsystem. By "atomic" I mean that once begun, the operation is guaranteed to complete before any other atomic operation can begin on the affected memory. An example that is commonly used in Windows is the "interlocked compare-and-exchange" instruction. x86/x64 actually provide a whole series of such instructions, working on various data sizes.

There are methods that allow safe serialized access to shared data without using such techniques, but they only work for a few special cases (e.g. "just one reader and just one writer") or for certain types of data.